# Sticky footer, with Concrete5 and Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, footer, sticky, concrete5

I'm making a website for a friend of mine, and he wanted it set up in a CMS. So i decided to make it in Concrete5 which is a CMS i know how to use. But i've encountered a website breaking error!
The sticky footer isn't working on Google Chrome?

http://test.gamersnation.dk/ <-- This is the website, and i just CAN'T seem to figure out whats wrong. I will link the CSS in a pastebin for you guys.

Pastebin - http://pastebin.com/RHjCaVGw

I hope for some help!

Answer (score 0):

A few things to look out for... it looks like you are loading external scripts as though they are locally installed in your theme folder.  That's throwing some errors in the console.  Also, once you clear that up, you will have more than one jquery instance loading (the version Concrete5 loads plus the one you are specifying in the footer).

Otherwise, try adding:

```
overflow: auto;
```

to the .content-wrapper selector.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup! I added the code in the selector now. Something positive definitely happend. But still seems like theres an error with the footer.

Comment: Hmm, seems like with overflow:auto; in .content-wrapper everything brakes and goes straight into the left area of the page.

Comment: I figured it out. I had a Div that didn't end properly. So i fixed it up, and shit works! Thanks for your input though! :)

Comment: good work figuring it out... I took a look at your screenshot and it really didn't look the same as what I was seeing, so it makes sense that the problem was something else.